# How exactly can I debug Cython with breakpoints?

Tags: python, debugging, cython

I have a large python codebase which I converted and compiled into cython modules. I now run the main function of my cython codebase using a python wrapper script file. In command line I run:

python wrapper.py args

where wrapper.py is composed of:

```py
import sys
from cython_main_module import main_function


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args_to_parse = sys.argv[1:]

    main_function(args_to_parse)
```

I have installed GDB using msys64 (btw i'm using Windows 10), but I do not know how to go about actually putting a breakpoint in one of the cython modules (i.e. a .pyx file which is where the code is) and then debug a configuration. Or, indeed, how to set this up. Further to this question, would it be possible to apply this debugger to a code editor, similar to how one is able to debug python using Pycharm. Thank you in advance.

I have tried starting python in the gdb, but I am struggling to start a particular python executable; I need to run python from the virtual environment in my project. I do not know how to do this in GDB mode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: breakpoints go in editors or ide's. if it is in code then use `print` or `logging` statements.

Comment: or use the `breakpoint()` statement.

Comment: D.L. I am not sure you understand how Cython works. OP wants to use GDB to debug native (not Python) code

Comment: Just to provide an update, I am trying to build gdb with python support from scratch, but gdb is never able to find debugging symbols in any python that I try to open it with. Therefore, I have tried to build python with debugging symbols, but, using msys2, I am getting an error regarding wcstok:

Comment: Python/initconfig.c:2283:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 2283 | config_envvars_usage()
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Python/initconfig.c:2289:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 2289 | config_xoptions_usage()
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: C:/msys64/mingw64/include/string.h:150:20: note: declared here
  150 |   wchar_t *__cdecl wcstok(wchar_t * __restrict__ _Str,const wchar_t * __restrict__ _Delim) _
_MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
      |                    ^~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:2505: Python/initconfig.o] Error 1

Comment: If i even manage to get gdb to work with python support, is there any way to integrate this with a text editor like pycharm? What I want is for developers to be able to code in Cython and debug using breakpoints and view the call stack, as if they were coding and debugging python in pycharm or c# in visual studio.  Please advise